# Does SQL Server 2005 pass error message numbers back to the asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, error-handling, referential-integrity

I'd like to get the message number and severity level information from SQL Server upon execution of an erroneous query.

For example, when a user attempts to delete a row being referenced by another record, and the cascade relationship is "no action", I'd like the application to be able to check for error message 547 ("The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint...") and return a user friendly and localized message to the user.

When running such a query directly on SQL Server, the following message is printed:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
<Error message...>
```

In an Asp.Net app is this information available in an event handler parameter or elsewhere?

Also, I don't suppose anyone knows where I can find a definitive reference of SQL Server message numbers?

Comment: Should I be handling errors like this?  Shouldn't I catch the error in the stored procedure and rollback the transaction?  Can I do that but still pass the error through to the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure - check out the [SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx) that gets thrown is something goes wrong on SQL Server.

It contains a collection of [SqlError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.aspx) elements, which contain a bunch of properties, including

- `Class`   Gets the severity level of the error returned from SQL Server.
- `LineNumber`  Gets the line number within the Transact-SQL command batch or stored procedure that contains the error.
- `Message` Gets the text describing the error.
- `Number`  Gets a number that identifies the type of error.
- `Procedure`   Gets the name of the stored procedure or remote procedure call (RPC) that generated the error.
- `Server`  Gets the name of the instance of SQL Server that generated the error.
- `Source`  Gets the name of the provider that generated the error.
- `State`   Gets a numeric error code from SQL Server that represents an error, warning or "no data found" message.

Comment: In this case I'm dealing with SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs.Exception in an ondeleted handler.  I was examining the exception with the VS debugger but looking in the wrong place.  (I think) I had to cast the exception as an SqlException - that seems to work anyway, giving me access to the members you listed.

Answer (score 1):

try this to see what all the messages are

```
SELECT *
FROM master.dbo.sysmessages
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server error messages are located in `master.dbo.sysmessages`

In ASP.NET if you catch the Exception as a SQLException then the error number and message will be available.

I think it is good practice to iterate through the SQL errors as there may be more than one

(untested)

```
try
{
// Do some stuff here
}
catch (SQLException sqlex)
{
foreach (SqlError error in sqlex.Errors)
{
Console.WriteLine(error.Number.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(error.Message.ToString());
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```